# Can anyone put a light on this ( txtView and button layout on android studio not working properly)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is my first ever android studio project and I started with creating some layout on my android application but when i run it on andrroid emulator it is not showing properly as seen on the picture. Can anyone help me with this ? what is causing problem here ?

Below is the xml code and picture attached. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thank you!!

[This is the android studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI6nr.jpg)

[This is the android emulator screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5VTX.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F5F6"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/totalNumber"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/total_numbers_in_the_lotto"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnPrint"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnPrint"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnPrint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EndNumber" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EndNumber"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="End Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/totalNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/totalNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/totalNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/StartNumber" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/StartNumber"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Start Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/EndNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/EndNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/EndNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Your Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/StartNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/StartNumber"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/StartNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="Print Your Lucky Numbers"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/resultLotto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/resultLotto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/resultLotto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/totalNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultLotto"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#F44336"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPrint" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: OMG, I was trying to sort it from last 2 days finding every possible things on internet. Damn you are a legend!! Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem are the `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Try to use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, for some reason Android Studio is giving you the necessary height to draw everything, but the real Android (emulator) is not calculating the height well. I can assume that the height has been calculated based on the constraints, but what you need is show always the right height for the text and reduce the padding based on constraints.

Comment: Yep it worked with that, also answered by Themelles thanks anyway